# Active Directory Trusts

Tags: active-directory

I have 2 domains on my active directory environnement.

There is a trust between this 2 domains:
([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()).GetAllTrustRelationships()

> ```
> SourceName     TargetName           TrustType    TrustDirection
> ----------     ----------           ---------    --------------
> mydomain.com   test.mydomain.com    ParentChild  Bidirectional
> ```

I am actually connected on mydomain.com DC with an "Enterprise Admins" member account.

I open mmc.exe and I add "Active Directory Domains and Trusts" item.

I can see a treeview with my "domain.com" as root and a sub-item for "test.mydomain.com".
I do not understand why but I can't do anything on test.mydomain.com: If I clic on this item, I get this error:

> The Active Directory Domain Services object could not be displayed
> Information for this object is not currently available possibly due to
> a network or Active Directory Domain Controller failure

How can I fix this ? What should I check ?

Thanks

Comment: Does test.mydomain.com resolve to a domain controller in the child domain?